# How to install the default Ubuntu terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have installed Ubuntu Server an then installed a minimal GUI using:

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

because I don't need Libre Office and all this bloat.
But now my terminal looks like this:

[image]

How do I install the default good looking terminal?

Comment: sudo apt install gnome-terminal ? But I think that should be installed. Check the "hamburger" icon, it will tell. I guess you'll need some decent fonts

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you've already tried customizing the look-and-feel of the console?

If not, click the menu icon (☰) then select Preferences, create a new Profile and customize at will. If you're missing any fonts, you can download the Ubuntu default fonts [here](https://design.ubuntu.com/font/).

Comment: There's no reason to download the Ubuntu fonts from the website. It's packaged, of course: [`ttf-ubuntu-font-family`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ttf-ubuntu-font-family)

Answer (score 1):

There are several terminal emulators you can install now that you have a desktop environment.

If you want specifically the one that ships with the current Ubuntu Desktop edition then that is `gnome-terminal`:

```
sudo apt install gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Cecilia Lopes I was able to do it:

```
sudo apt install gnome-terminal gnome-tweaks
wget https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/0cef8205-ubuntu-font-family-0.83.zip
unzip 0cef8205-ubuntu-font-family-0.83.zip
sudo cp -r ubuntu-font-family-0.83 /usr/share/fonts/
sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/fonts/ubuntu-font-family-0.83
sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/fonts/ubuntu-font-family-0.83/*
fc-cache -vf /usr/share/fonts/
fc-list|grep ubuntu
```

and then I was able to chose Ubuntu Mono font in gnome-terminal Preferences.

Comment: Uh, you can install the Ubuntu font using `apt`. It's [a package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ttf-ubuntu-font-family)